# SSAS (looking for mdx measure) count distinct customer in a category at a date

Tags: ssas, mdx, msbi

I have just implement a SSAS structure which deals with customer and newsletter subscription.

I'm dealing with a kind of simple issue that I do not solve at now..

Here is an simple extract of one of my fact table :

Date    |   cat     |   Contact

201401  |   noSub   |   Paul
201403  |   Multi   |   Paul
201602  |   Mono    |   jean
201604  |   Mono    |   Paul
201604  |   Multi   |   Paul
201609  |   noSub   |   jean
201703  |   Multi   |   Paul

I want to get a measure (contactNumber) which gives me how many Contact there are within a category at the time of the request..

I create this measure : (DC_Contact is a Count distinct of contact)

`[Measures].[ContactNumber] = 
    AGGREGATE( 
        NULL : [Period].[Per Quarter].CURRENTMEMBER
        ,[Measures].[DC_Contact])`

but when I check it in 201703, it gives me 

`noSub = 2 (excepted 1)
Multi = 2 (excepted 1)
Mono = 2 (excepted 0)`

And in 201604   I will have

`noSub = 2 (excepted 2)
Multi = 1 (excepted 0)
Mono = 1 (excepted 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for answering.
I find a solution to the issue

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[mono] AS 
filter(
    GENERATE(
        DynamicContactSet,  
        tail(
       -- ORDER(
            filter(
                [Contact].[Contact PMID].currentmember
                * {null : [Period].[Per quarter].currentmember}
                * {null : [Period].[Per week].currentmember}
                * [Category].[Category].[Category]  
            ,[Measures].[max_date]>0) 
       -- ,[Measures].[max_date],desc)
        ,1)
    ),cint([Category].[Category].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY)= 1
).count
, VISIBLE = 0; 

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[multi] AS
filter(
    GENERATE(
        DynamicContactSet,  
        tail(
       -- ORDER(
            filter(
                [Contact].[Contact PMID].currentmember
                * {null : [Period].[Per quarter].currentmember}
                * {null : [Period].[Per week].currentmember}
                * [Category].[Category].[Category]  
            ,[Measures].[max_date]>0) 
       -- ,[Measures].[max_date],desc)
        ,1)
    ),cint([Category].[Category].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY)= 2
).count
, VISIBLE = 0; 


CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[unsuscriber]  as 
filter(
    GENERATE(
        DynamicContactSet,  
        tail(
       -- ORDER(
            filter(
                [Contact].[Contact PMID].currentmember
                * {null : [Period].[Per quarter].currentmember}
                * {null : [Period].[Per week].currentmember}
                * [Category].[Category].[Category]  
            ,[Measures].[max_date]>0)
   -- ,[Measures].[max_date],desc)
    ,1)
    ),cint([Category].[Category].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY)=3
).count
, VISIBLE = 0; 


CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[notopin] as 
DynamicContactSet.count - (mono + multi + unsuscriber)
, VISIBLE = 0; 



CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[ContactNumber]  AS
CASE  
    WHEN cint([Category].[Category].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY)= 1 THEN mono
    WHEN cint([Category].[Category].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY)= 2 THEN multi
    WHEN cint([Category].[Category].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY)= 3 THEN unsuscriber
    ELSE notopin 
END
, VISIBLE = 1;
```

Then I Can get at anytime how much contact there are in a category :

```
SELECT [Measures].[ContactNumber] on columns 
 ,(

   {[Period].[Per Quarter].[month].[M01-2000] 
   ,[Period].[Per Quarter].[month].[M01-2005]
   ,[Period].[Per Quarter].[month].[M01-2007]
   ,[Period].[Per Quarter].[month].[M01-2010]
   ,[Period].[Per Quarter].[month].[M01-2015]
   ,[Period].[Per Quarter].[month].[M01-2017]
   ,[Period].[Per Quarter].[month].[M12-2017]}
   ,[Category].[Category].[Category]
) ON rows

FROM [BI SUBSCRIPTION]
where
{                          
   [Contact].[Contact PMID].[jean paul]  
   [Contact].[Contact PMID].[jean michel] 
   [Contact].[Contact PMID].[jean françois]    
   [Contact].[Contact PMID].[jean christophe]    
   [Contact].[Contact PMID].[jean rachid] 
}
```

But the bigger issue now is the performance...
But I do not see how improve perf without reduce data volume.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to help you has we lack of details regarding the structure of your cube but you should probably doe something using DistinctCount (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/distinctcount-mdx)

Don't hesitate to add more information regarding your structure, this should help to help you.